# Django looking for static file through wrong path...how do I change?

Tags: jquery, python, django

I am implementing Jquery into my Django base...well at least trying here. I have done the necessary steps from (http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/jquery.html), and I'm trying to run collectstatic in cmd to update static files, as that is what I believe is the main culprit in my Jquery code not running. My static folder is located in:

c:.../website/mysite/personal/static

However, I go to run collectstatic in cmd and I am getting the following error:

"FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3]The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\website\mysite\static"

Not sure why it is pulling from there. I do have a folder /website/mysite/mysite , but I don't believe that to be the issue at hand.

Below are my settings.py for static:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "/mysite/personal/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
```

Comment: `STATIC_ROOT` is an absolute path - try `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")`. You can remove the same line from `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Comment: I removed staticfiles_dirs all together, somehow collectstatic ended up working..for now that is...

Answer (score 0):

you can put this line  and delet old lines :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

i think it should be work.